Would have been vs Will have been
In the grammar book that I'm currently studying, the text differentiates these two expressions quite definitively:
"would have been" refers to an event that did not happen
"will have been" refers to an event that did happen
both address a past event, despite the latter sentence using "will".
To me, the distinction seems a little too strict and arbitrary; "would" seems to have, at least according to my own compiled memory of English use so far, replaced "will" for most intents and purposes.
Am I wrong in this assessment?

"Will have been" refers to an event that will happen (the "will" here marks the future). In practice, "will" seems to have replaced "shall" for marking the future or intentions, but many people still use "shall". Whether you can replace "will" with "would" depends on the context. For inviting someone to do something, or giving semi-polite commands, it would probably be fine. E.g. "Will you come with me?" vs. "Would you come with me?". For these two versions, "will you ..." to my ears sounds polite but more forceful, i.e. there's no option to decline it like there is with "would".

I think you need to explain more about what your grammar book is saying, and what examples it provides. Both "will have been" and "would have been" are used in multiple situations; sometimes they're substitutable with a change in meaning, sometimes not. Do you have a particular sentence in mind?

There is a distinction and I’ll do my best to explain.
“Would have been” relates to a circumstance which has not happened because of a decision that was made in the past.
“Had I worked harder at school, I would have been a Lawyer by now.”
“Will have been” relates to a point in time in the future relating to a current continuous circumstance.
“In 6 weeks, I will have been a Lawyer for 10 years.”
There may be some other contexts that I can’t think of right now but hopefully that helps.

It's not exactly clear to me that there is much difference, without additional context (like example sentences); but perhaps would have been can be replaced with "could have been", whereas will have been can be replaced with "must have been"/"has been"/"was"/"is".
So "would have" is something that could have happened (but maybe didn't), whereas will have means it definitely did happen.
Note that changing will to "may" changes the meaning from "must", so that it may have have happened, but equally it may not have.
